# "Requested OpenGL implementation is not supported. Implementation: 1" error in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

when i run this code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

I get this error

```
[6448:3156:0715/200747.900:ERROR:gl_surface_wgl.cc(399)] Unable to create pbuffer.
[6448:3156:0715/200747.900:ERROR:gl_surface_qt.cpp(197)] Requested OpenGL implementation is not supported. Implementation: 1
```

what is the cause and solution of this error?

or is there any alternative to QtWebEngineWidgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log points to a problem with opengl so you can change the settings:

```
# ...
QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL)
# or
# QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseOpenGLES)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# ...
```

See [Graphics Drivers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers) for more information